# Why my ctrl+semicolon was bound globally?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, keyboard-shortcuts, emacs, compiz

My ctrl+semicolon (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>;</kbd>) key seems combination to have been bound to some sort of broken auto-complete program. Whenever I am in typing mode(in terminal, nano, etc), my <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>;</kbd>) combination is bound to this program. I have no idea what it is. How do I identify and stop this?

[image: ctrl+semicolon in mint terminal]

[image: ctrl+semicolon in ubuntu terminal]

Comment: I don't know what you regard as a "normal" editor: command-line or GUI? There are two places that define short-cuts: system-wide short-cuts are defined in `Control Centre` -> `Keyboard Shortcuts`; while additional ones for terminals are defined `Edit` -> `Keyboard Shortcuts...`. One or other of these should list your `Ctrl+;` combination. I run Ubuntu Mate 16.04.2, and this short-cut is not predefined.

Comment: I have the same issue in `Debian GNU/Linux bookworm/sid` with Gnome 42.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is caused by an addon in fcitx named [Clipboard](https://fcitx-im.org/wiki/Clipboard). To disable it, simply open Fcitx Configuration -> Addon -> Clipboard, then either disable it or change its trigger key.

[image: Addon -> Clipboard]

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue with `Debian GNU/Linux bookworm/sid` and Gnome 42. It was driving me nuts since I had `Ctrl-;` bound in Emacs. I could not find the binding defined anywhere. Then, I ran,

```
gsettings list-recursively | grep -i "semi"
```

Lo and behold: `org.freedesktop.ibus.panel.emoji hotkey ['<Control>period', '<Control>semicolon']`.

Appending to irritation of modern hieroglyphs, I ran,

```
gsettings set org.freedesktop.ibus.panel.emoji hotkey []
```

That freed the keybinding.

Comment: This worked on Gnome 42 on Fedora. You saved me, thank you!

Comment: Thanks.  Worked for me, too.